# Cómo podría alinear textos de dos líneas diferentes de manera en que queden como dos filas de ladrillos en CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy  desarrollando una página web simple que te dice los rangos de peso según tu estatura y edad, el problema que tengo es que no sé cómo podría hacer esto de la manera más eficaz.
Las dos líneas están colocadas de manera horizontal mediante párrafos con la propiedad (flex-direction: row;) y la idea es que los números queden entre los espacios de las palabras.
Cualquier ayuda se agradece de antemano.
[image: Rango de pesos]

Comment: Podes poner tu codigo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que debes usar `grid` en vez de `flex` y agregar `div` vacíos para los espacios

```css
.grilla{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);
  width:100%;
}
.graf{
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grilla">
  <div></div>
  <div>54,9 kg</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>69,4 kg</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>83,8 kg</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>112,7 kg</div>
  <div></div>
  
  <meter class="graf" min="0" max="100" low="33" high="66" optimum="80" value="100"></meter>
  
  <div>Bajo peso</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Peso ideal</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Sobrepeso</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Obesidad</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Obesidad Morvida</div>
</div>
```

---

Comentarios no relevantes:

- kg es con `k` minúscula
- La separación decimal es con coma `,`

Comment: Muchísimas graaacias me sirvió mucho